# Http web request Accept and Expect difference

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-accept-language

I have been writing a C# program to deal with and send web requests and they seem to be working as intended, however I have in my code the following two headers within my `HttpWebRequest`:

```
request.Accept = "application/xml";
request.Expect = "application/xml";
```

I am a little confused of the difference or which way round these are, could some one please clarify to me which is which or if I am wrong. Am I right in thinking `Accept` is what I am expecting them to take from me me (e.g an XML) and `Expect` is what they should return to me, i.e. what I am expecting in return.

Have I got this wrong? a lot of the stuff I can find on-line in documentation is a little vague and confusing for me to understand, am I even using expect correctly or should it be something completely different?

Any clarification would be fantastic, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `Expect`. The `Expect` request-header field is used to indicate that particular server behaviors are required by the client. You do not specify MIME header types here as you do with `Accept`.

For more info see the HTTP/1.1 Definition at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html (`Expect` is section 14.20).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for the advice and link, I'll have a read of it, appreciated!